# SELinux is blocking VPN connections for non root users

Tags: fedora, rhel, openvpn, selinux

I want (open)vpn connections to be available to all users, but if I'm not root are blocked by SELinux.

I looked In `var/log/audit/audit.log` first in no permisive mode:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1659770552.275:309): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1923 comm="openvpn" path="/root/.cert/nm-openvpn/ie-dub.prod.blk.com_udp-tls-auth.pem" dev="nvme0n1p3" ino=802406 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

an after that I set permissive to see what is blocked:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1659770802.776:318): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=2124 comm="openvpn" path="/root/.cert/nm-openvpn/hu-bud.prod.blk.com_udp-tls-auth.pem" dev="nvme0n1p3" ino=802398 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
type=AVC msg=audit(1659770802.777:319): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2124 comm="openvpn" name="hu-bud.prod.blk.com_udp-tls-auth.pem" dev="nvme0n1p3" ino=802398 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
type=AVC msg=audit(1659770802.777:320): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=2124 comm="openvpn" path="/root/.cert/nm-openvpn/hu-bud.prod.blk.com_udp-tls-auth.pem" dev="nvme0n1p3" ino=802398 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1659770805.461:321): table=firewalld:6 family=1 entries=5 op=nft_register_rule pid=916 subj=system_u:system_r:firewalld_t:s0 comm="firewalld"
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1659770805.528:322): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
```

It seems that I need to change the context label for the *.pem files, but it is not clear what context to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the files in `/etc/openvpn`, you'll see that they have the `openvpn_etc_t` label:

```
# cd /etc/openvpn
# ls -lZ
total 0
drwxr-x---. 1 root openvpn system_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 0 Jun 10 13:36 client
drwxr-x---. 1 root openvpn system_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 0 Jun 10 13:36 server
```

If you had created your configuration files in this directory initially, they would already have the correct label. However, from the errors it looks like  openvpn is trying to read files from `/root`; this isn't generally a good idea, since it requires the service to have elevated privileges.

The easiest solution is probably to relocate your files to `/etc/openvpn`. Don't use `mv`, because this will preserve the existing (incorrect) labels. Something like this will work just fine:

```
tar -C /root/.cert -cf- . | tar -C /etc/openvpn -xf-
```

This would place the `nm-openvpn` directory in `/etc/openvpn` with the correct labels.

You will need to update your connection profile to use the certificates in the new location.

Comment: one can also use `mv -Z`.